# Discord.py Rewrite Cog: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a simple command that says hi with a cog in discord.py, but recieve an error:  `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`. I know that cogs should be used to organize a set of related commands. I was just testing so that I could create a more complex bot. I looked in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#quick-example), but didn't find anything significant. Maybe I am missing a very obvious thing. Please help. I am a beginner.
Here is my code:

```
class Test_Cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Command()
    async def sayhi(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('hi')


class Test_Application_Bot(commands.Bot):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Logged on as", self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # so that it doesn't respond to itself
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        print(message.content)
        if message.content == "ping":
            await message.channel.send("pong")

        await self.process_commands(message)


def read_token():
    with open("token.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines[0].strip()

def main():
    bot = Test_Application_Bot(command_prefix="!")
    bot.add_cog(Test_Cog(bot))
    bot.run(read_token())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Could you add the full error trace?

Comment: `@commands.Command()` should be `@commands.command()`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thank you! It works perfectly. @Anwarvic if you want the full error trace, it was ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "discord_bot.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Test_Cog(commands.Cog):
  File "discord_bot.py", line 11, in Test_Cog
    @commands.Command()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorator should be written with lower case letters
Instead of `@commands.Command()`
Try `@commands.command()`